# Get only 1 result per group of ID

Tags: mysql

I have a list of records (`domestic_helper_idcards`) and I want to return only one card per staff (`domestic_helper_id`) that is not deleted (`is_deleted = 0`), and that has the card_expiration_date furthest in the future (latest expiry date).

Have tried grouping and so on, but cant get it to work. Code below:

```
SELECT * FROM domestic_helper_idcard
where
is_deleted = 0
order by card_expiration_date desc
```

This returns the following (image):

[image]

I want only records with ID 4 and 5 to be returned. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a join with the subquery grouped  by `domestic_helper_id` with an aggregated  function eg: `max()`

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM domestic_helper_idcard d
inner join (
  select domestic_helper_id, max(id) max_id
  from domestic_helper_idcard
  where  is_deleted = 0
  group by  domestic_helper_id 

) t on t.domestic_helper_id = d.domestic_helper_id and t.max_id  = d.id

order by d.card_expiration_date desc
```

and as suggested by  Jens after clarification using max card_expiration_date

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM domestic_helper_idcard d
inner join (
  select domestic_helper_id, max(card_expiration_date) max_date
  from domestic_helper_idcard
  where  is_deleted = 0
  group by  domestic_helper_id 

) t on t.domestic_helper_id = d.domestic_helper_id and t.max_date  = d.max_date

order by d.card_expiration_date desc
```

Comment: After clarification you should not use `max(id)`, instead you should use `max(card_expiration_date)`

Comment: @RaymondNijland a) why you told it to me not to scaisEdge, b) If an id is not unique it is not an id!!

Comment: "i want to return only one card per staff (domestic_helper_id) that is not deleted (is_deleted = 0)," @RobertBenedetto notice that these queries can result into giving more then one domestic_helper_id because these queries does not handle ties.. If the id column column is unique then query 1 will return one domestic_helper_id

Comment: @Jens "why you told it to me not to scaisEdge" scaisEdge get's auto "pinged" because he is the one that answerd. "b) If an id is not unique it is not an id!!" we should not assume without seeing table structure to verify the id column is indeed unique..  Also i just now noticed i pinged the wrong person i should have pinged "Robert Benedetto" with that other comment..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I had to change to t on t.domestic_helper_id = d.domestic_helper_id and t.max_date = d.card_expiration_date, but then it worked fine. Thanks!!